# Background-image don't load an image

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I have a problem with using background-image in style in my HTML page.I am creating login page in my Django application and when I execute the page, the background image is not displaying. Interestingly, this code worked yesterday and not today.

I've already deliberately placed the image and the file in one folder to avoid path problems.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title> Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <style>
    body {
      margin-top: 20px;
      background: rgb(184, 213, 242);
    }
    
    .account-block {
      padding: 0;
      background-image: url('login.jpg') !important;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      height: 100%;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .account-block .overlay {
      -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
      flex: 1;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
    
    .account-block .account-testimonial {
      text-align: center;
      color: #fff;
      position: absolute;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 0 1.75rem;
      bottom: 3rem;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
    
    .text-theme {
      color: #5369f8 !important;
    }
    
    .btn-theme {
      background-color: #5369f8;
      border-color: #5369f8;
      color: #fff;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main-wrapper" class="container" style="text-align:center; width:100%;">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-xl-10">
        <div class="card border-0">
          <div class="card-body p-0">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="p-5">
                  <div class="mb-5">
                    <h3 class="h4 font-weight-bold text-theme">Login</h3>
                  </div>

                  <h6 class="h5 mb-0">Welcome back!</h6>
                  <p class="text-muted mt-2 mb-5">Enter your User ID and password to access admin panel.</p>

                  <form method="POST" action="">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="exampleInputText1">User ID</label>
                      <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="exampleInputText1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-5">
                      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                      <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme">Login</button>

                    <a href="#l" class="forgot-link float-right text-primary">Forgot password?</a>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-6 d-none d-lg-inline-block">
                <div class="account-block rounded-right">
                  <div class="overlay rounded-right"></div>
                  <div class="account-testimonial">
                    <h4 class="text-white mb-4">Test 1</h4>
                    <p class="lead text-white">"Test 2"</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <!-- end card-body -->
          {% for message in messages %}
          <p id="messages">{{message}}</p>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <!-- end card -->

        <p class="text-muted text-center mt-3 mb-0">Don't have an account? <a href="{% url 'register' %}" class="text-primary ml-1">register</a></p>

        <!-- end row -->
      </div>
      <!-- end col -->
    </div>
    <!-- Row -->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how placing them in the same folder alleviates path problems. However, I would try adding `background-position: center;` to ensure the image is centered. Without knowing any specifications of the image, it's hard to give an exact solution. Based on the evidence in question, I don't see how this shouldn't work for you.

Comment: when I am using in CSS : background-image: url(https://bootdey.com/img/Content/bg1.jpg); - it's work, but when I save this picture and add to my folder - nothing is displaying.

Comment: Have you opened the browser developer tools? Also, is the file accessible in your environment? Try supplying a full path just to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have created `content` folder and:  `background-image: url('../../static/app/content/login.jpg');`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong here but I would try out this solution.

Try changing

```
background-image: url('login.jpg')
```

to:

```
background-image: url('../indentification/login.jpg')
```

I'm not sure that you eliminated the path problem exactly.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help